# Cannot ping other LAN devices

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, lan, ping

I have a ZTE F618V2 that I got from my ISP. I'm trying to connect 2 devices using the 2 ethernet ports on the router(192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3, respectively), but they do not see each other. Pinging each other results in a "destination host unreachable".
The two devices in question are Windows machines, an 11 and a 10. They both have firewall disabled, file and printer sharing enabled.
Even if I use an android device through Wi-Fi as 192.168.1.2, I still cannot ping 192.168.1.3, and vice-versa. Same if the android device is on ethernet.
I have even attempted using the public IP address of the network, and I still cannot connect. Only if I disconnect from the network and use a different one, such as my mobile data, can I connect using the public IP address.
I've contacted my ISP, thinking it's an option inside the ZTE router, or something they have to enable from their HQ, but they said it should work out of the box, as should be a case with any normal router.
What else could I attempt? What could be the issue?

Comment: If you feel up to it, you can use Wireshark to monitor network traffic as you try to ping. You may be able to get more information this way.

Answer (score 0):

You wish to ping from win10 to win11. Ok, good.
But first let's shoot for some less ambitious goals.

Bring up win11 and try to ping the 192.168.1.1 router address,
or try to ping an internet address such as the 8.8.4.4 nameserver.
Having accomplished that you could move on to attempting the same
for win10, and then finally get win10 to ping win11.

The very first thing that happens is you plug in
an RJ-45 ether connector, and a "link up" transition happens.
Verify that, by looking for green LED on both win11 and router.
The port's LED should illuminate when you plug in,
and extinguish when you remove the cable.
Also, the router should be sending at least thirty broadcast
packets per second, some of them Spanning Tree BPDUs.
Often you'll be able to see LEDs flickering as packets pass through.

The next thing that happens, once the ether link is up,
is your win11 client should send a DHCP broadcast,
asking "what IP should I use?". We want to see that happen,
and see any replies that come back.
There's at least two debugging techniques.

To repeatedly experiment,
you can plug / unplug the cable,
or you can use:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

### 1 logging

One debugging technique is to rely on logging.
Navigate to Event Viewer,
Applications and Services Logs, Microsoft, Windows, Dhcp-Client,
Microsoft-Windows-DHCP Client Events/Operational,
and click the "enable log" checkbox.
Then monitor incoming events as you experiment.

### 2 wireshark

Everyone's favorite Swiss Army knife -- [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html)!

View all packets going over the win11 ether interface
as you experiment.
You should see a DHCP request, a DHCP reply, then
some ARP and ICMP traffic as you ping different hosts.

Post your observations and
let us know how it turned out for you!

Answer (score 0):

On some router , there is an option to enable/disable device communication inside your lan . The device can ping the router and access to the internet but cannot ping or see the other. You need to check your ZTE router administration website.